# How to synchronize HttpRequest or WebClient in Wp7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, webclient, httprequest

Now I know i can only dowload a string asynchronously in Windows Phone Seven, but in my app i want to know which request has completed.
Here is the scenario:
I make a certain download request using `WebClient()`
i use the following code for download completed

`WebClient stringGrab = new WebClient();
stringGrab.DownloadStringCompleted += ClientDownloadStringCompleted;
stringGrab.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(<some http string>, UriKind.Absolute));`

i give the user the option of giving another download request if this request takes long for the user's liking.
my problem is when/if the two requests return, i have no method/way of knowing which is which i.e. which was the former request and which was second!
is there a method of knowing/sychronizing the requests?

I can't change the requests to return to different DownloadStringCompleted methods!

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an interesting question because by default WebClient doesn't carry any unique identifiers. However, you are able to get the hash code, that will be unique for each given instance.

So, for example:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadStringCompleted);
client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://www.microsoft.com", UriKind.Absolute));

WebClient client2 = new WebClient();
client2.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadStringCompleted);
client2.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://www.microsoft.com", UriKind.Absolute));
```

Each instance will have its own hash code - you can store it before actually invoking the `DownloadStringAsync` method. Then you will add this:

```
int FirstHash = client.GetHashCode();
int SecondHash = client2.GetHashCode();
```

Inside the completion event handler you can have this:

```
if (sender.GetHashCode() = FirstHash)
{
    // First completed
}
else
{
    // Second completed
}
```

**REMEMBER:** A new hash code is given for every re-instantiation.

Comment: thanks! it's working...though i'll have to compare the integer hashcodes! thanks for your time and Help!

Comment: i had a shy at the answer above but found it was not suited for my program.... trying this one, thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

Why not do something like this:

```
void DownloadAsync(string url, int sequence)
{
    var stringGrab = new WebClient();
    stringGrab.DownloadStringCompleted += (s, e) => HandleDownloadCompleted(e, sequence);
    stringGrab.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(url, UriKind.Absolute));
}

void HandleDownloadCompleted(DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e, int sequence)
{
    // The sequence param tells you which request was completed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the requests are essentially the same, rather than keep track of which request is being returned. Why not just keep track of if one has previously been returned? Or, how long since the last one returned.

If you're only interested in getting this data once, but are trying to allow the user to reissue the request if it takes a long time, you can just ignore all but the first successfully returned result. This way it doesn't matter how many times the user makes additional requests and you don't need to track anything unique to each request.

Similarly, if the user can request/update data from the remote service at any point, you could keep track of how long since you last got successfull data back and not bother updating the model/UI if you get another resoponse shortly after that. It'd be preferable to not make requests in this scenario but if you've got to deal with long delays and race conditions in responses you could use this technique and still keep the UI/data up to date within a threshold of a few minutes (or however long you specify).

Comment: You are quite right...but i'm giving the user the option of rejecting requests that take long to respond. i needed the sequence of the request to update UI accordingly. As i store the data of the request which is to be shown when i get its response, i needed to have some kind of acknowledge data/sync!